Trying to use my first created Knowledge graph embeddings model
I'm trying to learn about creating and using knowledge graph embeddings models, I got a code, adapted it until I got no compiling or executing errors but now the predictions it mades are wrong. This is my code:
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import pandas as pd

# Load the knowledge graph dataset from a CSV file
kg_data = pd.read_csv("triplesData.csv")

# Assuming the CSV file has columns 'head', 'relation', and 'tail'
heads = kg_data['head'].values
relations = kg_data['relation'].values
tails = kg_data['tail'].values

# Create a mapping from entities/relations to unique IDs
entities = list(set(list(heads) + list(tails)))
relations = list(set(relations))
entity_to_id = {entity: idx for idx, entity in enumerate(entities)}
relation_to_id = {relation: idx for idx, relation in enumerate(relations)}

# Convert entities and relations to their corresponding IDs
head_ids = [entity_to_id[head] for head in heads]
relation_ids = [relation_to_id[relation] for relation in relations]
tail_ids = [entity_to_id[tail] for tail in tails]

# Create the input samples as a list of (head, relation, tail) tuples
samples = list(zip(head_ids, relation_ids, tail_ids))

# Get the number of entities and relations
num_entities = len(entities)
num_relations = len(relations)

# Define the knowledge graph embedding model
class KnowledgeGraphEmbeddingModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_entities, num_relations, emb_dim):
        super(KnowledgeGraphEmbeddingModel, self).__init__()
        self.emb_dim = emb_dim
        self.num_entities = num_entities
        self.num_relations = num_relations

        # Initialize embeddings for entities and relations
        self.entity_embeddings = nn.Embedding(num_entities, emb_dim)
        self.relation_embeddings = nn.Embedding(num_relations, emb_dim)

    def forward(self, samples):
        # Reshape the input samples
        head, relation, tail = samples[:, 0], samples[:, 1], samples[:, 2]

        # Get embeddings for head, relation, and tail
        head_emb = self.entity_embeddings(head)
        relation_emb = self.relation_embeddings(relation)
        tail_emb = self.entity_embeddings(tail)

        # Apply a score function (e.g., DistMult)
        score = torch.sum(head_emb * relation_emb * tail_emb, dim=1)

        return score

# Example usage
emb_dim = 10

# Create the model
model = KnowledgeGraphEmbeddingModel(num_entities, num_relations, emb_dim)

# Create the input tensor from the samples list
samples_tensor = torch.tensor(samples)

# Forward pass
scores = model(samples_tensor)

# Save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'kg_model.pth')

# Load the model for testing
model = KnowledgeGraphEmbeddingModel(num_entities, num_relations, emb_dim)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('kg_model.pth'))
model.eval()

def query_tail(head, relation):
    head_id = torch.tensor([entity_to_id[head]])
    relation_id = torch.tensor([relation_to_id[relation]])
    entity_ids = torch.arange(num_entities)

    # Create all possible combinations of head, relation, and tail
    heads = head_id.repeat(num_entities)
    relations = relation_id.repeat(num_entities)

    # Compute scores for all possible tails
    scores = model(torch.stack((heads, relations, entity_ids), dim=1))

    # Find the index of the tail with the highest score
    predicted_tail_idx = torch.argmax(scores).item()
    predicted_tail = entities[predicted_tail_idx]

    return predicted_tail

# Example usage of query_tail function
query_result = query_tail('Rome', 'capital of')
print("Predicted tail:", query_result)

and this is my dataset:
head,relation,tail
Paris,capital of,France
London,capital of,UK
Berlin,located in,Germany
Tokyo,capital of,Japan
Rome,capital of,Italy
Beijing,capital of,China
Moscow,capital of,Russia
Canberra,capital of,Australia
Madrid,capital of,Spain
Ottawa,capital of,Canada
Brasília,capital of,Brazil
New Delhi,capital of,India
"Washington, D.C.",capital of,United States
Amsterdam,located in,Netherlands
Vienna,capital of,Austria
Stockholm,capital of,Sweden
Copenhagen,capital of,Denmark
Athens,capital of,Greece
Lisbon,capital of,Portugal
Warsaw,capital of,Poland
Budapest,capital of,Hungary
Prague,located in,Czech Republic
Brussels,capital of,Belgium
Dublin,capital of,Ireland
Helsinki,capital of,Finland
Oslo,capital of,Norway
Reykjavík,capital of,Iceland
Bern,capital of,Switzerland
Luxembourg City,capital of,Luxembourg
The Hague,located in,Netherlands
Monaco,located in,France
Vatican City,located in,Italy
San Marino,located in,Italy
Andorra la Vella,capital of,Andorra
Vaduz,capital of,Liechtenstein

The problem is that when I tried prediction the tail of "Rome","Capital of" .. it always gives me something else than "Italy". What is the thing that I'm doing wrong?
or is there another approach to create KGE more effectively?
Thanks.
